# jqGrid allow only 1 sort direction

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, sortdirection

jqGrid's sort icon on the column header shows both up and down arrows. Is there a way to force the icon to show only 1 direction like only allowing ascending order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the jqGrid Event documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents). You could define your own sorting by returning `'stop'` on the `onSortCol` event. Something like this should work:

```
onSortCol: function (index, iCol, sortorder) {
    if (sortorder === "desc") {
            return 'stop';
    } else {
            //do regular sorting.
    }
}
```

Also if you do this on gridComplete it should hide the descending arrows:

```
gridComplete: function () {
    $('.ui-grid-ico-sort.ui-icon-desc.ui-sort-ltr').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899305/315935) I shown how to change the visibility of sorting icons. I modified for you the previous solution to show only the active sorting icon.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ShowOnlyCurrentSortableIcon.htm) demonstrate the results and shows the headers like this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

The code below shows the most important part of the code:

```js
var $grid = $("#list");

$grid.jqGrid({
    //... other jqGrid options
    sortname: 'invdate',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
        var $icons = $(this.grid.headers[idxcol].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico");
        if (this.p.sortorder === 'asc') {
            //$icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').show();
            $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc')[0].style.display = "";
            $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc').hide();
        } else {
            //$icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc').show();
            $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-desc')[0].style.display = "";
            $icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').hide();
        }
    }
});
// hide initially the disaabled sorting icon
$('#jqgh_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id) + '_' + $.jgrid.jqID(sortName) + '>span.s-ico').each(function () {
    $(this).find('>span.ui-icon-' +
        (sortDirection ? 'asc' : 'desc')).hide();
});
```

I tried to use `$icons.find('>span.ui-icon-asc').show();` in the `onSortCol` at the beginning , but has problems in the Google Chrome because the show() set `display: block` style on the `<span>` element. So I just removed the `display: none` style.