# jqGrid Sorting Arrows

Tags: jqgrid

For sorting, I would like to show only one arrow aligned with the column header.  I noticed that `viewsortcols` allows you to put the arrows horizontally (aligned nicely), but I was wondering if there were any tricks to just use a single arrow.  If sorted one way it points up, the other way it points down.

I came across [this grid](http://www.the-di-lab.com/demo/apples) that is doing it...but was having a little trouble understanding their code.  I do not need to use custom arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example which you reference uses very old version of jqGrid (version 3.4.3). So it can have another behavior of sorting.

One day I misunderstand one question and have answered on exactly your question. You find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9144955/315935). It uses [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ShowOnlyCurrentSortableIcon.htm) which create the results

[image]

and

[image]

[One more answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914163/315935) could be also interesting for you.

**UPDATED**: If you want to change position of the sort icon you can do this by adding the CSS like the follow

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-labels .s-ico .ui-grid-ico-sort {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

It will change the icon position to

[image]

and

[image]

See [the modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ShowOnlyCurrentSortableIcon1.htm).

Comment: A nice example...I just wish the arrow could be vertical-aligned with the title.  It looks a little strange to me.  I'm surprised that jqgrid doesn't offer the option.  But I might use your solution if no one else has any input.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @Beeffingers: What you want can be done with additional CSS setting. See my updated answer. You can set `margin-top` to some another negative value like `margin-top: -1px;` if you like to place both icons higher.