# Jqgrid - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, jqgrid

**Dynamic Column width According to Its Content**

I tried adjusting the column width dynamically according to the content this way ,by finding characters length of each row ,then finally getting the max length out of it  and setting it to grid column width.

```
loadComplete : function () {
                $("#grid").on("jqGridAfterLoadComplete jqGridRemapColumns", function () {
                var $this = $("#grid"),
                colModel = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
                iCol,
                iRow,
                rows,
                row,
                n = $.isArray(colModel) ? colModel.length : 0;
                var rowData = "";
                var rowDataLen="";
                var input = [];
                var divs = $( "div" );
                var colWidth=125;
                for (iCol = 0; iCol < n; iCol++) {
                            input = [];
                            for (iRow = 0, rows = this.rows; iRow < rows.length; iRow++) {
                                        row = rows[iRow];
                                        rowData = $(row.cells[iCol]).find(divs).html();
                                        if(rowData != undefined)
                                            rowDataLen = rowData.length;
                                        input.push(rowDataLen);
                            }
                            var finalWidth =  Math.max.apply(null, input);
                            if(finalWidth < colWidth)
                                finalWidth = colWidth;
                            $("#grid").jqGrid("setColWidth", iCol, finalWidth);
                            var gw = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','width');
                            $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridWidth',gw);
                       }                    
            });     
        },
```

and it is working fine.

However  it is too slow and getting  **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

error when I have more records like 500.

Can anyone help to tweak the above solution so that it can be faster?

## Here is my HTML Code:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:left;" title="Hot-forged Hot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forged." aria-describedby="grid_test">
<div style="max-height: 120px">Hot-forged Hot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forgedHot-forged.</i><br><br><i>tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</i></div></td>
```

**I am actually finding the max character size of the div content..i also tried directly taking the title attribute of `<td>` this way- `rowData = $(row.cells[iCol]).attr('title');` - but it is also giving the same error**

## colum model  formatter for fixed row height:

formatter : function(cellvalue){  if(cellvalue == undefined || cellvalue == null) {
            cellvalue = "";
        } 
        return '' + cellvalue + ''; },

Or how can i reduce the performace of this code? Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you posted is wrong, but I'm sure that you have other place of your code which is the origin of long `title` and long cell content.

The main error in the code which you posted: **you should don't make binding to the grid inside of `loadComplete`**. `loadComplete` will be executed multiple times. On every execution you add **one more** binding, which is wrong. Instead of that you should move `$("#grid").on("jqGridAfterLoadComplete jqGridRemapColumns", function () {...});` and set it before creating the grid. You should understand that `jqGridAfterLoadComplete` is event which will be triggered before `loadComplete` every time. I suppose that you produces recursion in some way.

I would strictly recommend you to migrate to [free jGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column)) or at least to use `autoWidthColumns` method which I published in `jQuery.jqGrid.autoWidthColumns.js` (see [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins)). See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26753600/315935) for more information and [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AutowidthColumn3_.htm). What you will need is just to use `$("#grid").jqGrid("autoWidthColumns");` before creating the grid. All required bindings (`$("#grid").on("jqGridAfterLoadComplete jqGridRemapColumns", function () {...});`) do the method `autoWidthColumns` internally.