# Why is outerWidth not working with jqgrid rows and columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I am using the adjusting Jqgrid Column width According to Its Content suggested in this post,

*[Jqgrid Column width According to Its Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322006/jqgrid-column-width-according-to-its-content)*

This way after loadcomplete event of jqgrid.

```
loadComplete : function () {

$("#list").bind("jqGridAfterLoadComplete", function () {
    var $this = $(this), iCol, iRow, rows, row, cm, colWidth,
        $cells = $this.find(">tbody>tr>td"),
        $colHeaders = $(this.grid.hDiv).find(">.ui-jqgrid-hbox>.ui-jqgrid-htable>thead>.ui-jqgrid-labels>.ui-th-column>div"),
        colModel = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        n = $.isArray(colModel) ? colModel.length : 0,
        idColHeadPrexif = "jqgh_" + this.id + "_";

    $cells.wrapInner("<span class='mywrapping'></span>");
    $colHeaders.wrapInner("<span class='mywrapping'></span>");

    for (iCol = 0; iCol < n; iCol++) {
        cm = colModel[iCol];
        colWidth = $("#" + idColHeadPrexif + $.jgrid.jqID(cm.name) + ">.mywrapping").outerWidth() + 25; // 25px for sorting icons
        for (iRow = 0, rows = this.rows; iRow < rows.length; iRow++) {
            row = rows[iRow];
            if ($(row).hasClass("jqgrow")) {
                colWidth = Math.max(colWidth, $(row.cells[iCol]).find(".mywrapping").outerWidth());
            }
        }
        $this.jqGrid("setColWidth", iCol, colWidth);
    }
});

}
```

Issue is i am getting zero for column width at this line

```
colWidth = $("#" + idColHeadPrexif + $.jgrid.jqID(cm.name) + ">.mywrapping").outerWidth()+25;
```

My column headers will have special characters this way,Though i have set autoencode : true. I am getting column width = 0. Do I need to parse these columns?

```
list_Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]
```

And in the same way i am getting zero for the row outerewidth at this line,

```
colWidth = Math.max(colWidth, $(row.cells[iCol]).find(".mywrapping").outerWidth());
```

as a result, all the time width of my rows are being 25.

Why I am not able to fetch outerwidth() in these cases for coulms and rows?

Can anyone help?

However, if i print .html(), I am getting the DIv content correctly this way,

```
var spans = $( "span" );
$(row.cells[iCol]).find(spans).html();
```

## HTML DIV Trace :

## TH

```
<th id="list_Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]" role="columnheader" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" style="width: 65px;">
<span class="ui-jqgrid-resize ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr" style="cursor: col-resize;">&nbsp;</span>
<div id="jqgh_list_Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
<span class="mywrapping">Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]<span class="s-ico" style="display:none">
<span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr">
</span><span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span></span></span></div></th>
```

## TD

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align:left;" title="FE" aria-describedby="list_Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]"><span class="mywrapping"><div style="max-height: 100px">FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFE</div></span></td>
```

Only problem is with width's..

## Column Model Fomatter:

```
formatter : function(v){ return '<div style="max-height: 100px">' + v + '</div>'; },
```

All my column names have special characters.Is thats is the reason? If so why the row/cell width is also retrived as zero.

I tried width/inner/outer nothing worked.

Can any one shed some light on this?

Comment: First of all the old way which I suggested originally (`$cells.wrapInner("<span class='mywrapping'></span>"); ...`) is **slow** because it modifies the texts. I would recommend you to use free jqGrid 4.9.1 or the latest code from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). Only if you can't migrate to free jqGrid you should invest more in debugging. **Could you post the demo which reproduces the problem?** What *column names* (not column headers) you use? If you use `name: "Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]"` then you make an error. Which HTML version you use? HTML5 or ???

Comment: @Oleg I use jquery 1.8 and jqgrid 4.4.1 and i cannot migrate as it is completely legacy code... is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, but I asked you more questions as you answered. Which `name` properties you use in the grid? Do you have `name: "Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]"` in `colModel`? Which HTML version you use? (How looks the first line with `<!DOCTYPE html...>`?). HTML5 for example don't allow to use spaces in id and `name` property of `colModel` will be used to build ids (like you have seen yourself). So you have to change names of column, but still can use old `colNames` which will be displayed for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you use `name: "Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]"` and uses the same text in `colNames` or you use `lable: "Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]"`. **You didn't posted JavaScript code** which you use, so I have to guess. Moreover it's unclear which dialect of HTML you use on the page (which `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` you use on the page). It's important to understand that jqGrid uses `name` property of `colModel` to build id elements of some internal HTML structures of the grid. You have seen it in HTML fragments which you posted. HTML5 don't allow to use spaces inside of `id` (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) for example). You can hind the restrictions of HTML4 for ids [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id). Moreover the symbols `[` and `]` are wrong too at least in case of using very old jqGrid 4.4.1. So the value `name: "Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]"` follows creating wrong HTML code dynamically. You should fix the values holding the same text displayed for the user (specified either by `colNames` or by `label` property of `colModel`). For example you can use

```
name: "Code_HEAVY_DUTY_50",
label: "Code [HEAVY] [DUTY] [50]"
```