# JQGrid header and column not aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid, and in a particular flow, the headers and columns are getting misaligned. I have found similar questions on stackoverflow, but the solutions have not worked for me. For the record, I have set the widths of the columns dynamically based on the content of their columns, using a block of code that was provided by Oleg in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322006/jqgrid-column-width-according-to-its-content). and then i am using setColWidth function of the jqGrid to set the grid width. I was debugging this issue that I am facing, and I had to look into jqgrid.setcolwidth.js where there is a function called dragEnd(). When i further looked into this function, I found that the first misalignment is happening in the following statement

```js
!0===d.forceFit?(e=
this.headers[c+d.nv].newWidth||this.headers[c+d.nv].width,this.headers[c+d.nv].width=e,this.headers[c+d.nv].el.style.width=e+"px",this.cols[c+d.nv].style.width=e+"px",0<this.footers.length&&(this.footers[c+d.nv].style.width=e+"px"),d.colModel[c+d.nv].width=e):(d.tblwidth=this.newWidth||d.tblwidth,b("table:first",this.bDiv).css("width",d.tblwidth+"px"),b("table:first",this.hDiv).css("width",d.tblwidth+"px"),this.hDiv.scrollLeft=this.bDiv.scrollLeft,d.footerrow&&(b("table:first",this.sDiv).css("width",
d.tblwidth+"px"),this.sDiv.scrollLeft=this.bDiv.scrollLeft));
```

This snippet is there in jquery.jqgrid.min.js and the alignment does not get distorted for all the columns, but for the 11th column. After it returns from these 2 function calls to my js file, the width of the header of that column is different from the width of the td's of the column(both .jqgfirstrow and .jqgrow)

I am not sure what to make out of this and am at a loss trying to find the root cause of the problem. It will be really great if any of you can shed some light on why it might be behaving like this, or maybe how does jqgrid exactly set the widths of its columns and headers.

Note: the value of forceFit is false there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you use some **old version of jqGrid**. I suggest you to upgrade to the latest version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (it's version 4.12.1, but I plan to publish 4.13.0 in the next days). Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop since the end of 2014.

I included many bug fixes and implemented new features in free jqGrid. the method `setColWidth` is included in the main code. Moreover there are many new features, like [auto-adjustment](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Auto-adjustment-of-the-width-of-column#auto-resizing-in-free-jqgrid-48) of column width based on the column content, `labelClasses`, `labelAlign` (see [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/26/)) and many many other features described in the readme to every published version and someone in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).

I suggest you to use free jqGrid. You can load it from CDN, for example by usage URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). I hope that the problem will be disappear automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. Ya i am using 4.6.0. Will change to the latest and check. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ori: You are welcome! I hope, it solves the problem. If not, then you should prepare the demo (in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for exmaple), which reproduce the problem. Please use non-minimized version of jqGrid (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) in the demo to simplify debugging.

Comment: I used the cdn for 4.12.1 and Bingo! there is no misalignment any more. Thanks again man. It has been the past 2 days I have been stuck with this. Tried all sorts of things. Had i asked this question earlier.. :D
Thats one big worry minus now.. :)