# JQGrid reduce the no of columns on window resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, responsive

I'm having a problem with jqGrid. I have a table with many columns. When I change the window or If open the web app in a mobile device, It should show only 4 or 5 columns in the grid table instead of many columns or else It should allow scrolling within the grid.  So how to reduce the number of columns in the JQGrid on the window resize event?.

I have tried like following and the resize event is working fine but look&feel is not good due to more columns in the grid and no scroll bar.

My Html,

```
<table id="list2"></table>
```

My jqGrid code,

```
 $("#list2").jqGrid({
    url: '/Project/GridData',
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['edit', 'view','id','Project_Name','Project_Name2','Project_Nam3','Project_Number','Project_Manager', 'Business_Unit', 'Project_Admin_Name', 'Remarks', 'Is_Active', 'Created_Date','Modified_Date'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'edit', index: 'edit', width: 55 },
        { name: 'view', index: 'view', width: 55 },
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 55, hidden: true },
        { name: 'Project_Name', index: 'Project_Name', width: 140 },
        { name: 'Project_Name2', index: 'Project_Name2', width: 140 },
        { name: 'Project_Name3', index: 'Project_Name3', width: 140 },
        { name: 'Project_Number', index: 'Project_Number', width: 140 },
        { name: 'Project_Manager', index: 'Project_Manager', width: 140 },
        { name: 'Business_Unit', index: 'Business_Unit', width: 140 },
        { name: 'Project_Admin_Name', index: 'Project_Admin_Name', width: 140, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', width: 180, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Is_Active', index: 'Is_Active', width: 100, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Created_Date', index: 'Created_Date', width: 150, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Modified_Date', index: 'Modified_Date', width: 150, sortable: false }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30,50,100,500,1000],
    //pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    loadonce: true,
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    pagepos: 'left',
    forceFit: true,
    shrinkToFit: false, // to enable the scroll bar in the responsive mode
    height: 500,
    width:1600,
    altRows:true,
    altclass:'myAltRowClass'

});
```

My Script,

```
var $grid = $("#ProjectSearchGrid"),
    newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true); // change the grid size based on parent div size
    $grid.jqGrid('setColProp','ProjectName',{width:100}); //change the column size for consistent look in the mobile device
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include always in your questions the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (or which you can use), and **the fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

If you use free jqGrid fork, then you can just add properties like `classes: "hidden-xs", labelClasses: "hidden-xs"` or `classes: "hidden-xs hidden-sm", labelClasses: "hidden-xs hidden-sm"` in the corresponding columns. See [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/andm1299/26/) from [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35503970/315935) for more details. If you don't use Bootstrap CSS, you can add the definition of `hidden-**` classes manually:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hidden-md {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .hidden-lg {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

If you use an old version of jqGrid and you really can't upgrade to free jqGrid or Guriddo then you can try to use

```
$(window).bind("resize", function () {
    // your resize handler
}).triggerHandler("resize");
```

and to call `hideCol` or `showCol` to hide/show the column on resizing. If you would need to follow the way, I'd recommend you to cache the list of hidden/visible columns to call `hideCol` or `showCol` only if the changes are really required. To detect the current resolution you can use `window.matchMedia` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)) or to get the width of some outer div of the grid (outer div of `<table id="list2"></table>`).

**UPDATED:** I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/n6g78two/, which uses jqGrid 4.6 and which demonstrates how to use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to hide/show some columns on resizing the grid. The demo hides the last column `"ComboDuration"` if the the width of view ports is 767 pixels wide or less. It uses the following code:

```
function hideOrShowColumns (e) {
    if (e.matches) {
        // we have view ports of 767 pixels wide or less
        $grid.jqGrid("hideCol", "ComboDuration");
    } else {
        $grid.jqGrid("showCol", "ComboDuration");
    }
}
var mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)');
hideOrShowColumns(mql);
mql.addListener(function (e) {
    hideOrShowColumns(e);
});

$(window).bind("resize", function () {
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", $grid.closest(".my-container").width());
}).triggerHandler("resize");
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thank you so much for your answer & help. And I am using the jqGrid version  4.6.0, I have followed "the demo" link but the scroll bar is not coming in my grid for the responsive devices, can you help me on this ?

Comment: @MdAslam: I appended **UPDATED** part to my answer. It describes https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/n6g78two/ demo, which uses jqGrid 4.6 and demonstrates the solution, which I described shortly before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods: showCol and hideCol to hide/show columns on condition.
Note that these method accepts array as parameter to show and hide more columns at once. Docs can be [found here.](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#method-list)

By example you can do this

```
var $grid = $("#ProjectSearchGrid"),
$grid.jqGrid("hideCol", ["Project_Name2", "Project_Name3"]); // hide these cols before resizing
newWidth = $grid.closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
$grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
```

Additionally to this if you use Guriddo jqGrid you can hide some columns when the grid loads in mobile device using the function **isMobile** .

By example to do this for column Project_name2 you can do

```
colModel: [
    ...
    { name: 'Project_Name2', index: 'Project_Name2', width: 140, hidden: $.jgrid.isMobile() },
```