# How do i change the mouseout color of the jqgrid sort icon

Tags: jqgrid

I have my sort icon which is black in color on mouse over and returns into color grey when mouse out. I want to change the color grey into white on mouse out. Since my column header has dark color so this icon colors are not clearly visible. Please help me to achieve this.

Also wanted to know how to change the default icon color. Thanks

UPDATED: jQuery jqgrid v4.4.4 from NuGet Package manager in visual studio.

Comment: Please include **in every your question** the information about the version of jqGrid and the fork. It would be helpful to include guiStyle (CSS frameworlk) which you use too (jQuery UI or Bootstrap). If you report a problem with the car, then the solution can depend on the car, which you use. It could have electric motor or drive with Gasoline/Diesel fuel, it could be a tractor, a truck, a race car, a bus, ... It could be modern car or a 100 years old retro car... I can continue. The structure and the content of sorting icons is different in different versions and forks of jqGrid.

Comment: In general the color and background-color on hovering will be defined by CSS which you use (jQuery UI theme or Bootstrap theme). One can, for example, create custom theme (see [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), for example) or to overwrite one of CSS rules of jQuery UI theme or Bootstrap theme, but one have to know which CSS framework and **in which version** you use. The structure of CSS rules of jQuery UI, for example, are changed in last versions.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your feedback. I'm sure I will definitely mention version in my every question. Please find the updated question for version. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but customization of jqGrid 4.4.4 has not much more sense today like  customization of Windows NT 3.5 or adapting your web site for IE4. Free jqGrid has absolutely another possibilities of the usage sorting icons and the icons in general. It contain two default **icon sets**, which can be easy customized. The sorting icons supports `showOneSortIcon: true`, `threeStateSort: true`, `sortIconsBeforeText: true` and the possibility to define your own `$.jgrid.builderSortIcons` method to replace the full content of sorting icons. The solution for jqGrid 4.4.4 has no value for other users.

Comment: I recommend you uninstall NuGet Package [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/) 4.4.4 and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.13.6 instead. You will be able to customize the sorting icons like it's described in UPDATED part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3616481/315935). By the way, the recommended way of the usage jqGrid in Internet environment would be loading it from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).