# How to always show sort arrrows?

Tags: free-jqgrid

By default free jqGrid shows arrows only on a sorted column.
I need to show arrows always. I can alter CSS like

```css
  .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-sortable .s-ico {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
```

, but I suspect there is an option for this.

[image]

Comment: You expose "I expect a option' - but did you have read the docs? There is a option for this purpose **viewsortcols**  (need to read it - it is not a single value). You just need to find it in free jqGrid documentation. If it is not available you can find it in Guriddo jqGrid JS [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/)

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I didn't manage to find docs for free jqGrid except https://free-jqgrid.github.io/. No even list of possible options there. And could not found the option investigating the code. But it seems the doc's you have provided work for free jqGrid at least partially.

Comment: free jqGrid is a clone, mostly it should be compatible with Guriddo jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid has `viewsortcols` option (see [old documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)), which is supported by free jqGrid too. The default value of the option is `viewsortcols: [false, "vertical", true]`. The first value of `viewsortcols` array specifies whether the sort icons should be shown always or not. Thus to implement your requirements you need just add the option

```
viewsortcols: [true, "vertical", true]
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/L417gcwf/72/ for example.

If you have an interest for more advanced customizing features of free jqGrid you can find in "UPDATED" part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616481/315935) for example.